# sklearn.KNeighborsClassifier - What would be the reason for unchanging accuracy despite varying k?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

I'm working on a data project that requires that I compare the results after executions with different k values. My dataset consists of 33887 samples and 2304 features. To do this I just compare the accuracy percentage between different k value experiments. For some odd reason, the percentages all seem to be relatively the same.

Here is my configuration and the functions I use to get my predictions to later calculate the accuracy:

```
knc = KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='ball_tree', n_neighbors=3, weights='distance')
knc.fit(features, classes)
pred_list = knc.predict(test_features)
```

And then I'll do the same thing but with 5 neighbors, then with 7 neighbors.
My accuracy (with my particular dataset) is always around 40% no matter the value of k. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Without any info about your data how could we possibly answer?

Comment: @Julien sorry about that I'm using a newer version of this [facial expression dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge/data) which has 33887 samples and 2304 features (48 x 48 pixel vluess). The features are all integers between 0 and 255  and the class values are between 0 and 6, 0 being angry for example and 3 being happy.

Comment: Maybe you should do some pre-processing on the data. Like normalization of samples.

Comment: @VivekKumar thanks for your response, but theoretically what effects would doing that have on the results?